# Multer with node.js / react-native not working

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, axios, multer

I'm creating an application with reaction-native, and I'm using an image picker to select an image and click the button to create a part that sends the image to the node.js server.

However, in the process of uploading an image, other additional information is normally stored in mysql, but images are not stored in the upload folder.

Multer version 1.4.2.
Node.js version 16.12.0

in react-native code ( data to node.js)

```
onPress={() => {
                  if (this.state.image === null) {
                    alert("이미지를 넣어주세요");
                  } else {
                    Alert.alert(
                      "구인 공고를 등록할까요?",
                      "등록후, 수정할 수 없으니 꼼꼼히 확인 부탁~!!",
                      [
                        {
                          text: "Cancel",
                          onPress: () => alert("취소하였습니다."),
                          style: "cancel"
                        },
                        {
                          text: "OK",
                          onPress: async () => {
                            const formData = new FormData();
                            formData.append("db_title", this.state.title);
                            formData.append("db_wtype", this.state.type);
                            formData.append("db_sdate", this.state.start);
                            formData.append("db_edate", this.state.end);
                            formData.append("db_money", this.state.money);
                            formData.append(
                              "db_address",
                              this.state.address
                            );
                            formData.append(
                              "db_description",
                              this.state.addition
                            );
                            formData.append("file", this.state.image);
                            formData.append("db_stime", "9");
                            formData.append("db_etime", "18");
                            formData.append("db_smin", "00");
                            formData.append("db_emin", "30");
                            await AsyncStorage.getItem("pubKey").then(
                              (pubKey) => {
                                formData.append("db_pubkey", pubKey);
                              }
                            );

                            const {
                              data: { result }
                            } = await axios.post(
                              "http://127.0.0.1:4000/upload",
                              formData
                            );
                            console.log(result);
                            alert(result);
                            this.props.navigation.navigate("Announce");
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                      { cancelable: false }
                    );
                  }
                }}
```

in my node server code

```
const multer = require('multer');

const _storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, '/upload')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
  })
const upload = multer({ storage: _storage });

router.post("/", upload.single("file"), function (req, res) {

  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.body.file);

  Article.create({
    db_title: req.body.db_title,
    db_wtype: req.body.db_wtype,

    db_sdate: req.body.db_sdate,
    db_edate: req.body.db_edate,

    db_stime: req.body.db_stime,
    db_etime: req.body.db_etime,

    db_smin: req.body.db_smin,
    db_emin: req.body.db_emin,

    db_pubkey: req.body.db_pubkey,

    db_money: req.body.db_money,
    db_address: req.body.db_address,
    db_description: req.body.db_description,
    db_img: req.body.file
  })
    .then(result => {
      console.log("result : " + result);
      res.status(201).json({ result: "공고가 등록 되었습니다." });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error("err : " + err);
    });
 });

 module.exports = router;
```

this is node.js console log
[image]

- edit image picker (this.state.image)

```
    _pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3]
    });

    console.log("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ");
    console.log(
      result
    );
    console.log("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ");
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ image: result.uri });
    }
  };
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with the code you have given. Please make sure that you have a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)...

Comment: @LinusUnnebäck Update my post! Please check post~

Comment: It seems like `this.state.image` contains the url to the file, but I can't tell since you haven't included the code that sets it...

Comment: @LinusUnnebäck i forget it, sorry I edited my post again!

Comment: you are just storing the uri to the image as a string here `this.setState({ image: result.uri })`. So that will only send the string `"file:///example.jpg"` to your server instead of the file. I'm not familiar with how FormData works on React Native but this might help you: https://dev.to/naderalfakesh/uploading-files-in-react-native-470m

Comment: @LinusUnnebäck Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the path made by multer:

change:

```
db_img: req.body.file
```

to

```
db_img: req.file.path
```

Comment: I change path like that but server return Request failed code 500.

Comment: Try to see what `req` actually contains. Did multer populate `req.file`? you can add `console.dir(req.file)` after the other two console statements.

Comment: it return undefined but `console.dir(req.body.file)`return location of files

Comment: Looks like multer middleware is not being used somehow -- normally it should be the opposite -- `req.body.file` `undefined`, and `req.file` is an object populated by multer. You can add some logging to the `destination` and `file` functions to see if they even run.